# How can I refresh a ListView in a Fragment from the main Activity?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-listview, android-fragments

I have a `MainActivity` which contains a tab bar with two fragments: `MainFragment` and `WishlistFragment`. They both extend as `ListFragment`.

When someone touches a menu item from the Option menu, I want the ListView within the Fragment that *is showing* to refresh its list using its custom adapter called `LazyAdapter adapter`.

So in here is where I want the refresh to go in my `MainActivity` code:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {   
     switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_edit:

               // find out which fragment is showing here
               // refresh the fragment's listview here
               // adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

               return true;
        }
}
```

How can I do this? I am not sure how to call forward into the fragment and how to determine which fragment is showing.

Here is how I have my tabs set up in `MainActivity`:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Main").setTabListener(this));
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Wishlist").setTabListener(this));
}

public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    // When the given tab is selected, show the tab contents in the container
    ListFragment newfragment = null;

    switch (tab.getPosition() + 1)
    {
    case 1:
        newfragment = new MainFragment();
        break;

    case 2:
        newfragment = new WishlistFragment();           
        break;
    }

    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, newfragment)
            .commit();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I do this?

Step #1: Fix your implementation of `onTabSelected()`. You do not want to be creating a new fragment each time the user chooses a tab. Instead, you want to have two fragments, held onto by the activity in data members, and use those in the `replace()` transaction.

Step #2: When needed, call `getSelectedNavigationIndex()` on the `ActionBar`, use that to choose which of the two fragments you need (obtained from the data members mentioned in Step #1 above), and call some method on the fragment to do what you want.